# How to fix seekbar pointer for live video streaming in tvOS

Tags: ios, swift, tvos, apple-tv, avplayerviewcontroller

I need to handle seekbar in tvOS for live video which is coming through m3u8 file.I am using default player in AVPlayerViewController.As per my observation from other apps seekbar pointer is fixed at last point of it.

Here is the code to play live video:

```
    var playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerViewController.view.frame = view.bounds
    let str = "Video.m3u8"
    let newURL = URL(string: str)!
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: .init(url: newURL))
    let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)       
    playerViewController.playbackControlsIncludeTransportBar = true
    playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = true
    playerViewController.player = player
    addChild(playerViewController)
    player?.play()
```

Please help if anyone having some idea about it.